# UpdateMethod in GridView extends the width of whole page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

My web forms's UpdateMethod which when I click on the 'Edit' button, it automatically extends the width of my whole page resulting in having the user to horizontally scroll it.

What I mean is the Fields boxes actually are too long which causes the problem for me.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: simply set the width of the textboxes. you can specify templates to use in edit mode I believe.

Comment: Fields that don't need to be edited can be set to `ReadOnly="true"`. I'm not sure which control you are using due to no code in your question.